# Simple Future: "I will go to the United States" or "I will go the United States"

Tags: future-tense

I read about simple future [in this link](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-future-tense/) and it says simple future form is:

> Subject + will + infinitive without to

So, which one is correct in the simple future form:

1. I will go to the United States
2. I will go the United States

It feels like the second one makes no sense to me, but according to the formula, it seems if we want to use simple future, we should use the second one, right?

Comment: Correct, the second one is ungrammatical. Note that there *are* narrow senses of ***go*** that can be used as a transitive verb, but they're not what is meant here.

Comment: @linker As you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Without to" here means the infinitive without a preceding *to* as marker: that is, *I will go* rather than *I will to go*.

The *to* **after** *go* is the head of the preposition phrase designating the goal.